# How can I change the default location of the Adobe Premiere Pro (creative cloud) media cache location?

Tags: active-directory, deployment, adobe

Adobe Premiere Pro on Windows machines stores its 'media cache' files in the %appdata% directory. On our network, this is redirected to a server share, and consumes significant amounts of storage space, while suffering increased latency for the user.
Each user can manually change the setting in the UI, and store these files elsewhere. This appears to modify a Current User registry key.

I work at a school, and relying on the students to change this setting correctly is a recipe for disaster!

I'm also under additional constraints, in that I have no access to group policy, and also have no ability to change the folder redirections or try to add exceptions for this particular folder.

I need a way to change the *default* location of the media cache to the local drive (C:) rather than the user's %appdata% folder.

Context: Windows 7 64-bit, Adobe Creative Cloud 2015, Windows Server 2012 enterprise domain.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

P.S. I would have added more meaningful tags, but don't have the reputation.

Comment: if %appdata% is redirected it's usually to cater for roaming profiles, I.E your students don't always sit at the same terminal or classroom - and consider other scenarios, not just this one. now your students will need to go back to their prior terminals to ensure their profiles on adobe match.

Comment: What's in the cache, and have you checked with Adobe about whether this is a good idea or not? If your students are swapping around among machines, then from the Adobe tools's perspective, the contents of the cache keep changing when the tool isn't looking. Is that going to affect operation? Will rebuilding the cache every time the tool starts be worse than the network latencies?

Comment: Adobe's advice us to store the profile on the local machine, and provide a user by user mechanism of achieving this. I'm just trying get to set it by default. Our current solution is to clear the caches from the server by script, which means that the cache must be rebuilt even if the users access the same machines. Due to server capacity limitations which I can't change, we cannot leave these large caches on the server.